# Ruby: How to sum values of multiple JSON objects into one object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have two JSON objects like this:

```
object1 = {
"Oct 2019": 100,
"Nov 2019": 100,
"Dec 2019": 100,
"Jan 2020": 100,
"Feb 2020": 100,
"Mar 2020": 100,
"Apr 2020": 100,
"May 2020": 100,
"Jun 2020": 100,
"Jul 2020": 100,
"Aug 2020": 100,
"Sep 2020": 100
}

object2 = {
"Oct 2019": 50,
"Nov 2019": 50,
"Dec 2019": 50,
"Jan 2020": 50,
"Feb 2020": 50,
"Mar 2020": 50,
"Apr 2020": 50,
"May 2020": 50,
"Jun 2020": 50,
"Jul 2020": 50,
"Aug 2020": 50,
"Sep 2020": 50
}
```

How can I sum the values of `object1` and `object2` so the resulting json object looks like the following?:

```
result = {
"Oct 2019": 150,
"Nov 2019": 150,
"Dec 2019": 150,
"Jan 2020": 150,
"Feb 2020": 150,
"Mar 2020": 150,
"Apr 2020": 150,
"May 2020": 150,
"Jun 2020": 150,
"Jul 2020": 150,
"Aug 2020": 150,
"Sep 2020": 150
}
```

(The values in this example are the same for every month, but in my application they are all different values.)

Comment: There is no JSON here. JSON is text by definition, you use a [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html) with [Symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Symbol.html) keys. `{ a: 1 }` is short for `{ :a => 1 }`, the same applies for your dates. `{ "Oct 2019": 100 }` is short for `{ :"Oct 2019" => 100 }`. Note that generally speaking you should avoid dynamic symbols, since they are never garbage collected. When working with dates using a string is probably the better fit. `{ "Oct 2019" => 100 }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, but I find the easiest is to use the form of [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to compute the values of keys that appear in both hashes being merged.

```
object1.merge(object2) { |_k,v1,v2| v1+v2 }
  # = {:"Oct 2019"=>150, :"Nov 2019"=>150, :"Dec 2019"=>150,
  #    :"Jan 2020"=>150, :"Feb 2020"=>150, :"Mar 2020"=>150,
  #    :"Apr 2020"=>150, :"May 2020"=>150, :"Jun 2020"=>150,
  #    :"Jul 2020"=>150, :"Aug 2020"=>150, :"Sep 2020"=>150}
```

The three block variables, `_k`, `v1` and `v2`, are defined in the doc. As is common practice, I've begun the name of the common key (`_k`) with an underscore to signal to the reader that it is not used in the block calculation.

---

If there were three or more such hashes to combine, write:

```
object1.merge(object2, object3, ...) { |_k,v1,v2| v1+v2 }
```

---

Another way of doing this is quite simple:

```
keys = (object1.keys + object2.keys).uniq
  #=> [:"Oct 2019", :"Nov 2019",..., :"Sep 2020"]
keys.each_with_object({}) do |k,h|
  h[k] = object1.fetch(k,0) + object2.fetch(k,0)
end
  #=> {:"Oct 2019"=>150, :"Nov 2019"=>150,..., :"Sep 2020"=>150}
```

See [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).

One could replace `objectx.fetch(k,0)` with `objectx[k].to_i`, as `nil.to_i #=> 0`, but I don't think that reads as well.

This could be extended to summing over three or more hashes in the obvious way.

Comment: For the OP, it's worth noting that this (as with most !-suffixed methods) is a mutative operation - it changes the original input. If you want to preserve the original hash and return a new object as the output, just `dup` it first to operate on a copy of it. `object1.dup.update(...`

Comment: @Chris, thanks for the heads-up. I changed `update` to `merge` to avoid mutating `object1`.